# Workflow will not transition to the next step or move to the "else" branch

Tags: workflow, 2-step-verification

Workflow will not transition to the else statement or the next step.

[image]

Comment: Is the workflow ending without any action? Does it hang 'In Progress'?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** your workflow will never go to the **else** statement if the **default** `status` value is `choice1`

In this case, it will go to the **If** section then pause then **wait** until the **status equal to choice1 again!!**

[image]

So it will never match the **else** condition that is `status` **not** equal to `choice1` because the **wait** action wait until the value becomes `choice1`.